# Is there an alternative for fontconfig?

Tags: software-recommendation, font

I have been a Linux user for years and now I might switch to Apple.

I use [fontconfig](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/) for font configuration including default font replacement and setting stylistic sets for OpenType fonts.

I have been trying to find an alternative for macOS. FontBook does not provide such ability and some apps provide the typography setting but they are not system wide.

Is there an alternative or a way to use fontconfig on macOS?